# MySQL Create View from 2 different tables and columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a view of 2 tables.

Currently, I am using the line below and this works fine, but I am getting too much information back, I need to be more selective and choose columns:

first table

```
wp_cart66_orders and i need to pull 
bill_first_name_, bill_last_name

status=, new or shipped etc...
```

2nd table

```
wp_cart_66_order_items
description, quantity
```

I am not sure if I need to create a view or just use this query.

Also, I might need to be pointed in the right direction on how to create it if that is the case.

```
select wp_cart66_orders.*, wp_cart66_order_items.*
from wp_cart66_orders, wp_cart66_order_items
where wp_cart66_orders.id=wp_cart66_order_items.order_id
    and wp_cart66_orders.status = 'new';
```

Thanks.

Comment: a view's only useful if you plan on re-using the underlying query in other locations, or are using it to filter data before presenting it to a user.

Comment: side note.. i am using mysql workbench and have tried to use the above query to create a view but something is not correct

Comment: Mark yes, i am basically exporting that query data every time and "fixing" it in excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your selective columns, your join explicitly, and reanme the common column names from two tables.

```
create view OrderItemsVW
as 
select wp_cart66_orders.bill_first_name as Bill_First_Name,   
       wp_cart66_orders.bill_last_name as Bill_Last_Name,  
       wp_cart66_orders.Description as OrdersDescription,          
       wp_cart66_order_items.Description as OrderItemsDescription
from wp_cart66_orders 
inner join wp_cart66_order_items
    on wp_cart66_orders.id=wp_cart66_order_items.order_id
where wp_cart66_orders.status = 'new';
```

Comment: wow, that's perfect. i see exactly how you did this now. i also did not know that i could have these on different lines. makes it so much easier to read. Thank you

Comment: is this typical to name views with WV? i just want to make sure if i need to do this again i do it right with the naming conventions

Comment: For view naming convention, normally I follow CamelCase rule, take the underlying entity name + VW. VW is not necessary certainly.

Answer (score 0):

A view will somehow be faster and can be reused. However, you may also just use your select query.

```
select wp_cart66_orders.*, wp_cart66_order_items.* from wp_cart66_orders, wp_cart66_order_items where wp_cart66_orders.id=wp_cart66_order_items.order_id and wp_cart66_orders.status = 'new';
```

this will only work if wp_cart66_orders and wp_cart66_order_items have the same columns.

Comment: it'll work fine. it's not a union query, it's just a lazy-syntax join.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **as** operator or list every column you want:

Select table1.col1 AS mycolname, table2.col4 AS mycolname2...

or

Select table1.col1,table2.col4 ...

Comment: select wp_cart66_orders.bill_first_name AS First_Name wp_cart66_order_items.description AS Order

Comment: like that? when you say mycolname you mean what i want it to show up as in the view or query window?

Comment: and do not forget to separete everything with a comma

Comment: select wp_cart66_orders.bill_first_name AS FirstName, wp_cart66_order_items.description AS Order;
am i missing something